# Running a scrapy spider from django app

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I am new to Django and I am trying to create a website that takes in user input (URL) and starts a scrapy spider using that input. The problem is I can't seem to start the spider from within Django. I keep getting the error:

```
ImportError: No module named Spider.settings
```

I have added the following lines to my Django settings:

```
import os
from sys import path
c = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(str(c)+'/projects/Spider')
d = os.getcwd()
path.append(d)
os.chdir(c)
d = os.getcwd()
os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Spider.settings'
```

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: this is very broad in order to achieve you may need to reconfigure everything .. How far you achieved ?  I have django app that can act like actual project but inside one app called `crawler` that's actually `scrapy`... And I used that for crawling only. if i want to run then i enter into the shell and I run.. But what you trying to achieve is not possible but simply i tried like `Popen(['/path/', 'scrapy'])` gave me permission denied error. may be if you solved this permission.. I think you are good to go ..

Comment: Hey the way that im doing it right now is by creating a python function that does a os.chdir into the project folder where i am keeping scrapy. This seems to be working for now but I dont think its a long term solution.